# How can I run mrjob with no input file?

Tags: python, mrjob

I have a mrjob program, and just get data from sql database, so I don't need read local file or any input file, however mrjob forces me to 'reading from STDIN', so I just create an empty file as input file. It's really ugly, is there a way to run the job with no input files?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried piping the output from mysql to mrjob? Something like:

```
mysql -D database -u user < test.sql | python mrjob_script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Go [here](http://mrjob.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guides/writing-mrjobs.html#data-flow-walkthrough-by-example) and look for the section called "file options." that should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

How about just use `/dev/null`? It doesn't remove the input requirement, but you don't need to create an empty file every time, it is always there.

```
python your_mr_job.py /dev/null
```